# datatable loop performance

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, for-loop

I have a question about loop DataTable in C#

I have a DataTable has about 20.000 rows and 60 columns

I want to write a SQL query to insert all of data in DataTable to database

I'm using My Sql

this is my SQL syntax:

```
"Insert into a values (...), (...), (...), ..."
```

"(...)" is all data in one row

this is C# code:

```
DataTable myDataTable; // myDataTable has 20.000 rows and 60 columns
string mySql = "insert into a values "
for(int iRow = 0; iRow < myDataTable.Rows.Count; iRow++)
{
     mySql += "(";
     for(int iColumn = 0; iColumn < myDataTable.Columns.Count; iColumn++)
     {
          string value = myDataTable.Rows[iRow][iColumn].ToString()
          string parameter = "@" + iRows.ToString() + iColumns.ToString();
          // here is some code for add "parameter" and "value" to MySqlCommand
          mySql += ","
     }

     // remove "," at the end of string mySql
     mySql  = mySql.SubString(0, mySql.Length - 1);

     mySql += "),"
}
// remove "," at the end of string mySql
// after that, I will execute mySql command to insert data into database here
```

when I run that code, It is take a lots of time to finish

I try change from "string" to "StringBuilder", but it is just faster a little.

How can I make the code run faster?

Thanks for all supports.

Comment: What is *here is some code for add "parameter" and "value" to MySqlCommand*?

Comment: Can't you use SqlBulkCopy or LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @Debug Your suggestion to `SqlBulkCopy` might need some review: *I'm using My Sql*

Comment: "comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, value).DbType = DbType.String;" // this is code using Parameter I used in my code. thanks.

Comment: It's probably not productive to hammer your MySQL server with hundreds of KB of SQL. Consider sending smaller batches, and in parallel.

Comment: To start with I would suggest measuring the time to build the SQL string and the time for it to execute the statement so you know whether it's DB related or code related. I would have expected StringBuilder to have more of an impact at improving the performance but we have no indication of the actual times you are experiencing.

Comment: `string parameter = "@" + iRows.ToString() + iColumns.ToString();` What does this produce for row 1 and column 11, and then row 11 and column 1?

Comment: I know. thanks. if I send a large data to insert using MySql, MySql will be crash. And I will execute insert data for each 500 rows. but, I worry about my code is not good about performance because the time to execute 2 for loop is so long.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: thanks. but that code just using for explain my idea. it make clear about my question. in real code, I add columsName + iRow + iColumn for parameter. My code has not Runtime Error. but take a lots of time. I think I will change my Idea for loop data in DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked for some timing information in a comment, but I then noticed this line of code:

```
mySql  = mySql.SubString(0, mySql.Length - 1);
```

I would suggest removing that from your loop and having slightly smarter code to only append the commas when needed.

For example, in the inner loop, add the comma to the `mySql` variable before each parameter instead of after, except for where `iColumn == 0`. That would stop the unnecessary comma being at the end of the string each time.